# How to raise a 401 (Unauthorized access) exception in Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

As the title said, I need to raise (from the C# code behind a custom SharePoint page) a 401 error page. Any help?

Comment: Kindly refer the link below, [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/Errorhandling_in_Webparts.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/Errorhandling_in_Webparts.aspx)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized access");
```

Answer (score 3):

If the exception is SharePoint related it's best to throw a SharePoint exception

```
throw new SPException("Not Authorized");
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spexception.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

Comment: SharePoint doesn't support MVC applications

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
throw new UnauthorizedAccessException($"Some message");
```

Comment: `UnauthorizedAccessException` is a system exception with a specific meaning, which shall not be used for user defined purposes.

From microsoft.com:

>The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.unauthorizedaccessexception?view=net-5.0